# Receive response of http request in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

So I am trying to get a way to display the content of a http response made by clicking a button on a webapplication and display it in a chrome extension.

The http request is to an API and responds with 1 line of data, so i'm trying to capture this, whenever a request is sent off to a specific url and store the response of the request as a variable of some kind .

So far I've followed this guide to get an understanding:

https://betterprogramming.pub/chrome-extension-intercepting-and-reading-the-body-of-http-requests-dd9ebdf2348b

This is nearly what I want to achieve but I Cant get it to work

Im hit with the error "Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'"."

Not really sure how I can just listen for the response of a certain request, any help?

Source code:

Manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "SafePaste",
  "description": "Build an Extension!",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
  "permissions": [
    "clipboardRead",
    "clipboardWrite",
    "storage",
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "host_permissions": ["https://demogamesfree.pragmaticplay.net/gs2c/v3/gameService/"],
  "content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["contentScript.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }]
}
```

contentScript.js

```
function interceptData() {
  var xhrOverrideScript = document.createElement('script');
  xhrOverrideScript.type = 'text/javascript';
  xhrOverrideScript.innerHTML = '
  (function() {
    var XHR = XMLHttpRequest.prototype;
    var send = XHR.send;
    var open = XHR.open;
    XHR.open = function(method, url) {
        this.url = url; // the request url
        return open.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    XHR.send = function() {
        this.addEventListener('load', function() {
            if (this.url.includes('<url-you-want-to-intercept>')) {
                var dataDOMElement = document.createElement('div');
                dataDOMElement.id = '__interceptedData';
                dataDOMElement.innerText = this.response;
                dataDOMElement.style.height = 0;
                dataDOMElement.style.overflow = 'hidden';
                document.body.appendChild(dataDOMElement);
            }
        });
        return send.apply(this, arguments);
    };
  })();
  `
  document.head.prepend(xhrOverrideScript);
}

function checkForDOM() {
  if (document.body && document.head) {
    interceptData();
  } else {
    requestIdleCallback(checkForDOM);
  }
}
requestIdleCallback(checkForDOM);
function scrapeData() {
    var responseContainingEle = document.getElementById('__interceptedData');
    if (responseContainingEle) {
        var response = JSON.parse(responseContainingEle.innerHTML);
    } else {
        requestIdleCallback(scrapeData);
    }
}
requestIdleCallback(scrapeData);
```

devtools.html

```
<script src="devtools.js"></script>
```

devtools.js

```
chrome.devtools.panels.create("MyPanel", null, 'panel.html'
```

panel.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script src="panel.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

panel.js

```
chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(request => {
  request.getContent((body) => {
    if (request.request && request.request.url) {
      if (request.request.url.includes('<url-to-intercept>')) {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            response: body
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put xhrOverrideScript.innerHTML inside a separate .js file, and instead use

```
xhrOverrideScript.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('./script.js');
```

Add this to the manifest to allow the file to be executed and commujnicate with background page.

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
{
  "resources": ["your_script.js"],
  "matches": ["https://*/*", "http://*/*"]
}
  ],
  "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": [
      "https://www.crunchbase.com/*"
    ]
  },
```

Then add a message listener in background page like this

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(async (request, sender, 
sendResponse) => {
  console.log(" Message From Injected Script ")
  console.log(request)
  if (request.message == "Intercepted Request Response") {
      console.log(request.Intercepted_response)
      sendResponse("done")
  }
})
```

And finally in the script injected:

```
function sendResponsetoBackground(response) {
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
  CE_id,
  { message: 'Intercepted Request Response', intercepted_response: response },
  (response) => {
    console.log('Response sent to Background page', response);
  }
);
  }
```